# Poor treatment of new users - especially those asking interesting questions

Tags: discussion, closing, closed-questions

Have others noticed a tendency for new users of mathSE to be treated poorly by existing users? The worst cases remind of some low-brow college fraternity where new users are expected to show they have earned their stripes, rather than being judged on the merit of their questions.

See, for instance, the complaint posted here yesterday: [How can I quit this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26663/how-can-i-quit-this-site) , complaining of exactly this behaviour.

I have encountered a surprisingly large number of interesting, or tricky, or research-level questions (i.e. where textbook solutions do not likely exist) posed by new users, ... and in return for asking an interesting question (rather than their homework), two things happen:

a) An existing user writes a comment quip like:  "What have you tried?"

b) Then the gang frat behaviour follows, and the interesting question is closed down.

An example is this question:

[The pdf of multiple independent gamma random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2636950)

or this question (now removed):

[PDF of the product of a standard Normal and a squared Normal](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2359678)

... still currently CLOSED.

---

**UPDATE**

Since this seems to have become a bit embarrassing to those involved, i.e. the inappropriate closing down of an original research question on mathSE, someone has now deleted the question, so that others here cannot see it and make up their own minds.

Here is a verbatim copy of the OP's clarified question:

> Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ be independent random variables.
>
> Is it possible to find a closed-form solution for the pdf of $Y=Z X^2$? I am also interested to find the characteristic function of $Y$.

**Here is a  $2^\text{nd}$ example:**

[distribution of Uniform to the power of Uniform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1968194)

**Here is a $3^\text{rd}$ example:**

[Distribution of X³ / Y when X and Y are uniforms distributions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2397891)

---

While this might look like a simple question, for anyone who is familiar with the subject matter, it plainly is not simple, and I am not sure if a 'closed-form' solution even exists. Asking the OP what s/he has tried is frankly insulting and pointless, because it does nothing to progress the answer. That is a comment suited to someone posting their homework: and this is plainly not a homework question. What role is a moderator performing in deleting a question like this?

There are a number of concerns here:

- The first is the closing down of genuinely interesting or difficult or research questions on this site. That is what I would hope is the real purpose of this site --- not just to see the same homework questions again and again and again
- The second is the treatment of new users that are ultimately the mechanism for growth and interest
- The third is that experienced users who are *not* familiar with a particular subject matter are closing down questions that they themselves could not answer, or do not realise are interesting questions ... and they are shutting down the question presumably simply because the person asking the question is 'new'. That does not seem to be a good reflection on the site either, nor a valid basis for closing interesting questions.

---

**What have you tried?**

There are a number of existing questions on meta about people commenting "What have you tried?" See, for instance:  [What did you try?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13351/what-did-you-try/13352) and [What have you tried? Is this homework? You will get more help if ...](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8947/what-have-you-tried-is-this-homework-you-will-get-more-help-if/) and more recently [A criterion for distinguishing between two kinds of questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26659/what-have-you-tried)

I personally think answering "What have you tried?" is perfectly fine if the question is a homework question. My area of concern is when questions that appear to be simple, but are in fact complicated, get shut down, perhaps because they are being interpreted as homework questions, when they are not. In my opinion, the fact that someone is new is often used as an information signal to suggest that this is likely to be a low-quality question ... but that is *not* always the case.

Comment: For information: "**Say I have X∼N(a,b) , a∼N(0,1) and Y=a(X^2) . What is the distribution and characteristic function of Y**" is the version of the question that was asked originally and is also the version that got closed (up to formatting improvements made by somebody else). Further  "returned to original - still requires clarification from OP" is what you wrote as edit message in a latter version. Given that you ought to agree with a closure. If the question *now* should be clear, post a request in the  reopens request threads.

Comment: There are folks that disagree with you on the particular question to which you link.  There is a dedicated meta thread for requests and justifications for the reopening of a question.  Go there.  Otherwise, you are ranting with only one sample, and drawing conclusions based on that post.  In particular, your third point you make accusations about experienced users who close, including "they are shutting down the question presumably simply because the person asking the question is "new""  That's an accusation that just doesn't apply to most users.

Comment: That said, I agree that in this as well as various others cases "What have you tried?" might not the best way to communicate the shortcomings of the question and a different and/or more detailed explication could be more helpful. The issue is not only, or even mainly, the lack of an attempt.

Comment: There is no way one user can take away any vote to re-open.  Both quid and I are referring to the dedicated meta thread to deal with this issue on a case by case format: [requests for reopen, undelete](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/25505#25505)

Comment: To add to what @amWhy said:  votes to reopen (as well as votes to close) expire after some time. So rather than being removed by somebody, it just was dropped by the system after some time.

Comment: I did recently vote to re-open -I don't know how long that vote lasts. In any event, this is not about the specific question - it is about the general issue, because I have noticed the same issue several times. I am not quite sure what happens to closed off questions (since I was looking for some of the others and don't seem to find them) - do they get deleted eventually?

Comment: If the score of the question (and answers) is low, it gets autodeleted after some time. If not, it may  or may not get manually deleted (by votes of 10k+ users or mods); just depends on whether somebody bothers to vote.

Comment: wolfies: if you're characterizing the comments from a user below the linked question, you are absolutely incorrect about said user's experience in the topic.  Own your claims against others.  "To me it seems .... ".  "I wonder if [this something] is the case?"  And refrain from making judgments which you present as "claims of fact" about users you don't know.

Comment: To the third bullet point: I generally only close questions with content I don't fully understand after having viewed the votes on the question as well as the comments.

Comment: @amWhy While I appreciate your comments (in particular as to any imperfections on my part), they do not unfortunately address the question at hand. The simple fact is that genuinely interesting questions are being closed down - esp from new users (previous examples I have been looking for have been expunged from the site), while drossy boring 'how many balls in a bag"  'solve my homework for me' questions not only are tolerated, but dominate.

Comment: @amWhy wrote:  `There are folks that disagree with you on the particular question to which you link`  Again, I think you miss the point. I believe that any imperfections in the original question have long been resolved (I personally asked the OP to clarify several key aspects), the OP addressed those issues in comments, and the question was then updated by me to reflect same. Are you suggesting that there is still something unclear about the question, or ill-suited to this site? Moreover, this is not the first time the same issue has happened - and it usually happens with new users

Comment: @wolfies  I have not missed your "point".  I simply don't fully agree with it.  Because someone disagrees with you doesn't entail they must be missing your point.  You write: `Have others noticed a tendency for new users of mathSE to be treated poorly by existing users? ... I have encountered a surprisingly large number of interesting, or tricky, or research-level questions (i.e. where textbook solutions do not likely exist) posed by new users,`  Then you ought to be providing more links to the "surprisingly large number of interesting questions" which get closed.

Comment: @amWhy Unfortunately, the previous examples that came to mind have now been deleted from the site, which *is* rather the point.

Comment: If you continue trying to claim that "The simple fact is that genuinely interesting questions are being closed down ... ", you'll need to provide in your post, if "interesting = what you yourself find interesting" (in which case this post here is primarily opinionated, or if you have any objective criteria to define precisely what counts as an "interesting question" that most users can agree upon.

Comment: @wolfies So we are to take your perception that there is a "tendency for new users of MSE" are poorly treated, as "the way things are here"?  Are we to accept your perception that "a surprisingly large number [how large?] of interesting questions .... posed by new users" as fact?  This site is not meant for folks to make generalizations from only one example, especially when the example supports its closers, and not your contention it was closed because the user was new.

Comment: To me, interesting includes 'has not been solved before' -- as distinct from 95% of the questions on the site which are textbook questions.

Comment: wolfies:  I agree there are far, far too many textbook-style questions.  But have you the experience necessary to know when any one of the surprisingly large number of interesting, is interesting (has not been solved before)?

Comment: @amWhy I am not concerned with why the question was closed - I am concerned why it remains closed, after the problems were corrected. You have not provided any suggestion to date of anything that is inappropriate with the question at hand .. nor why it would be appropriate to relegate it to the bucket  list of expunged/deleted questions, when far from being dross, it appears to propose the finding of new previously unknown solutions that one would think would be encouraged here.

Comment: Any way, I need to leave this question for now.  Say what you feel you need to say; I may not see it, because I am choosing to not engage any further with you on this matter.

Comment: Which "question at hand"?  I sure have, provided many suggestions of many things inappropriate with your question, as well as feedback.... just because you don't agree with it doesn't mean I failed to provide it.  Cheers!

Comment: **UPDATE** The post still exists, and many folks can still see it via your link.  You are the one, who by this post, brought delete votes to it, not to hide it (such a post is never hidden), but because you directed folks to a poorly posted question of not much quality:  no effort from the OP existed; the post was a plea for the asker for some answerer to tell them what the answer/result is.  That's hardly a research level question.  You undermine your concern with such an example.  Don't lose your cool and make a fool of yourself via your very recent edit.

Comment: Message reads:  "This question was removed from Mathematics Stack Exchange for reasons of moderation."

Comment: On your edit: The question is still there in my comment, isn't it? And here is the last version "Let $Z \sim N(0,1)$ and $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ be independent random variables.

Is it possible to find a closed-form solution for the pdf of $Y= Z X^2$? 

I am also interested to find the characteristic function of $Y$." for reference. That said, it was not I that deleted it, and I would see some advantage in it being visible for now.

Comment: Deletions are soft-deltions;  users with the appropriate privilege (10k+ or mod) can see all deleted posts. It could be a good idea you get familiar with the basic mechanics of the site.

Comment: And to be clear, there were five distinct users who voted to close that question, and another three users (non of which contributed votes to close) who deleted it.

Comment: @amWhy I think you have described the problem perfectly - there are 5 experienced users of mathSE who voted to close down a perfectly valid original research level question. Say no more.

Comment: First of all, it was/is not a research level question, nor was it perfectly "valid" to post a question with no context.  I haven't read the reasons for closure, but if I *had* downvoted, it would be due to the lack of any elaboration on, motivation for, explanation of the question.  That is, I could have (and would have) voted to close as "off topic: lacking context".  And it isn't only "experienced users" who can vote to close (another term you failed in your rant to define): what is an "experienced user" in objective measurement only?

Comment: How would you define a research level question? Can you solve it? And if you don't know that it is a research level question, should one really be closing off questions one does not understand or appreciate the difficulties of?

Comment: You're the one who introduced the description: "research level question".  So you first, then we'll compare notes. Best to you!  ;-)

Comment: If I cannot solve a calculus 1 integration problem, does that make it a research level question? Because I can tell you right now, I can barely integrate $e^x$.

Comment: Also note that the asker of the linked post in question, on the very next day, [posted a similar question with no context](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360988/sum-of-chi-square-and-normal-distributed-variables) (no work or thoughts on what to do, no motivation, no references), a question which implicitly asks for someone to answer the asker's question for him/her.

Comment: Will you stay on topic and stop ever expanding your commentary?  You are now at the point where you are abusing meta. You should not be using your question to continuously add more and more questions who's outcomes you disagree with.  Again:  If you believe a question should be reopened or undeleted, there already exists such a thread (which I've already posted for you)[requests for reopen and/or undeletion votes](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio/25505#25505); don't keep clogging up meta with rants.

Comment: @amWhy Quite the opposite, you asked for additional examples, and I am now providing them where I can find them (i.e. where nice questions from new users still exist, and have not been permanently lost by being deleted from mathSE).

Comment: "To me, interesting includes 'has not been solved before' -- as distinct from 95% of the questions on the site which are textbook questions."  So questions about any of the unsolved questions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_mathematics) and questions from incompetent users who claim they have solved them in one paragraph, or two, are automatically interesting because they are unsolved questions?

Comment: "Research level"? There is nothing "research level" in the fact that, if $Y=ZX^2$ with $(X,Z)$ independent, then the most classical change of variable yields $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=x^{-2}f_X(x)f_Z(x^{-2}y)$, which in turn implies that $f_Y(y)=\int_\mathbb Rx^{-2}f_X(x)f_Z(x^{-2}y)dx$, as is explained in every decent textbook on the subject and has been explained countlessly many times on the site à propos various distributions and various transformations. Now, if one is actually alluding to the task of finding a formula for $f_Y$ in terms of usual functions when $f_X$ and $f_Z$ are normal, then ...

Comment: ... one should note that 1. this is probably not doable, 2. this is not interesting. So much for "genuinely interesting or difficult or research questions"... And we should probably refrain from commenting how ridiculous the gratuitous slander "experienced users who are not familiar with a particular subject matter are closing down questions that they themselves could not answer, or do not realise are interesting questions" sounds when applied to question 2359678, right?

Comment: I believe that the question *What have you tried?* is a very good question for everyone, especially  for new users of Mathematics Stack Exchange. Now, if the new user (you can imagine an user that is member for few days and that don't know how type tex) don't answer it, and I downvoted his/her question after 5 minutes...what can I say? That it is a no sense $100$%. On the other hand if you want to discuss or to defend a cause the beginning *The worst cases remind of some low-brow college fraternity...* is wrong. That is my opinion: you can omit what does not fix the situation. Good luck.

Comment: By coincidence, [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2368344/principal-value-of-mathbbe1-x-for-x-sim-mathcaln-mu-sigma2) was recently posted. I think it is a well-posted question in all the ways the question prompting this thread isn't.

Comment: @wolfies As another note, while you may find the question interesting, it is likely the case that this question isn't interesting to many, and in fact, many users have probably seen variations of that question already, if they've been on the site long enough.  The first few times I saw some neat proofs of $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2^k=2^n-1$ were interesting, now... not so much... indeed, sometimes I feel like such questions are too repetitive for someone like me who more or less skims the hundreds of questions that come to the site everyday...

Comment: @Did I don't think any of the simplistic methods you have proposed have any likely prospect of producing the OP's request for a closed-form solution. Perhaps you may wish to look at the Mellin transform approach of MD Springer, but the solutions are messy and complicated, and the original problem posed by the OP (sadly now deleted by mathSE) lies outside even Springer's extensive compendium of published papers on the Algebra of RVs, or the work of many subsequent authors. Perhaps you don't consider any of this to be research. Touché.

Comment: ... And if so, your stated disregard for the plethora of published results that have helped define texts like the Johnson and Kozt compendiums as 'not being research' appears to be both unfortunate, and frankly disparaging of the profession.

Comment: I may well have been interested to attempt an answer, but the question was CLOSED off before I had a chance to spend any time on it, thus preventing me from posting a solution, if I had something useful to contribute. But more importantly than anything I may have to say, it prevented anyone else from attempting a solution, and that is a very un-academic approach to the universe. It is also the opposite for why this site exists (or is meant to exist), at least as I understand it.

Comment: Michael Hardy Indeed, your comment on this question cannot help it, and can only hurt it, since your endorsement ...  umm ... how do I say this gently:  Your support has come to mean very little.

Comment: @amWhy : I do always try to avoid acrimony when posting here. This is the only time when I felt it was obligatory to say something that I knew might upset people.

Comment: @amWhy : My most recent question was very obviously phrased to avoid acrimony, and five on-topic comments appeared followed by one intended one expressing anger at things I'd said in earlier postings, anger justified at best only by disagreement with my position, and then another that said I had come here looking for an argument. I was deliberately trying to avoid an argument: I merely asked whether a certain kind of question was considered by those who usually close questions to be one that ought to be closed. And here is a fact: I don't know.

Comment: @amWhy : If I post here simply asking whether people consider a certain kind of question to be one that ought to be closed, am I looking for acrimony?

Comment: @amWhy : It is _not_ about me. But "meta" is a place where failure to toe the party line is forbidden.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Apparently you didn't see the structure of the comment you wrote. Flat denial of characterization a of your behavior in a completely different thread, complaints of persecution against yourself, then name-calling. There is *very* little to justify keeping that comment, namely that you are trying to assert you disagree with the closing. Please do not continue to muddy the waters here with your own issues with other threads.

Comment: @rschwieb : So I am forbidden to mention other threads, but others who do so when it's totally off topic are ok?

Comment: @rschwieb : You posted a comment in a recent thread that I read repeatedly and tried to understand and couldn't. It said something about my choice of an "unquestionable example". The only "example" that I knew you might be referring to was a question I had chosen precisely because it was a case in which reasonable people could disagree about the decision to close the question, thus a highly questionable example chosen for that reason. I asked you to clarify. What were you trying to say about that?

Comment: @MichaelHardy "The closing of this question is an act of cowardice to a degree that is seldom seen." Why is it an act of cowardice? I didn't and wouldn't vtc it, but I can't see anything *coward* in doing it.

Comment: @quid : For two reasons. Firstly, the usual one: Those who go against certain party lines on "meta" are quickly shut down. That was proved beyond a doubt by voluminous circumstantial reasons, but recently also by two smoking guns: Two of those who do this admitted it. The second one is more involved. I have on many occasions, and recently, gone against party lines and been attacked for it, in numerous cases saying the same things that are said in this posting, and as soon as I posted a comment saying I might post my own answer,$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ action was taken to close this question and was complete within about a couple of minutes, this when several individuals who attacked me for disagreeing with doctrine were participating in the comment thread.

Comment: @MichaelHardy first votes to close this question were cast *hours* before you showed up. Chill out.

Comment: On your newest edit: did you bother to check who the unnamed user is that in a way was the final cause for quitting? The global situation on the site is a lot more complicated and multi-faceted than you might think.

Comment: "What role is a moderator performing in deleting a question like this?" No *moderator* was involved in the deletion.

Comment: @wolfies Also, I note the [second "example" you link us to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1968194/distribution-of-uniform-to-the-power-of-uniform/) is a question you answered, and was accepted by the asker.  So I think you've conflicting interests with that question.

Comment: @amWhy  lucky for all I was able to squeeze an answer in and help the OP out before they closed it off.

Comment: As pointed out in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26611#26614), if a user gets an answer (before putting question on hold) they might be less motivated to improve the question and get it reopened. So that might get the OP closer to question ban. So it is not that clear cut whether *lucky for all* is actually the correct phrase to use for situation like this.

Answer (score 16):

> My area of concern is when questions that appear to be simple, but are in fact complicated, get shut down, perhaps because they are being interpreted as homework questions, when they are not.

I don't<sup>*</sup> care whether it's homework or not. It's getting shut down since it's simply a problem statement assigned to MSE.

I don't care if the post is an overly terse description of an interesting question — the onus is *still* on the poster to show the basic research effort. In the case of a "research level question", it's *even more important* that the poster share the basic research with the reader.

And as a happy side effect, doing so will make the post stand out from the bad questions.

---

That said, I do think there is some poor treatment involved, but not the way you describe. In my opinion:

- we don't effectively describe what a post needs to stop being a bad question
- ad-hoc advice given in comments about how to improve the question is often even less effective at conveying this

So we have well-meaning people trying to help improve the question — and maybe the original poster even does their best to follow that advice — but frustration ensues because it's not done in a way that really effects much improvement (and may even make it worse) and the question gets closed anyways.

Disclaimer: the above description is skewed towards describing the more problematic interactions and may not reflect the average.

---

Note I neither affirm nor deny that the question under discussion is a research level question. Also, I'm not entirely convinced that the question the original poster was intended is the same question as the one wolfies conceived of after reading the post.

<sub>*: Actually, I do care, but have left that topic out of the discussion.</sub>

Comment: Downvotes on meta express disagreements hence one can understand some downvotes in the present case, as for every post which actually expresses an opinion, but *a vote to delete*? What can possibly be the point of a vote to delete this?

Comment: This answer seems entirely based on factual error. Maybe I'll post an answer of my own....

Comment: Hmmm.  I see no factual error here.  (Though some folks do confuse fact with fiction.)

Answer (score 4):

> Asking the OP what s/he has tried is frankly insulting and pointless, because it does nothing to progress the answer.

One utility of an OP's sketching of what he or she tried is giving Readers a starting point to explain a procedure to solve the problem.  In the absence of this information, guesswork is involved in picking a starting point.  Often this leads to an inefficient use of the OP's and the Reader's time.  Either the Answer might cover material (i.e. definitions and other basic considerations) already known to the OP, or it might launch into a discussion that sails over the OP's head.

There are (as is often pointed out in Comments) other ways to add context besides sketching an approach.  See the previous discussion here, [How can this on-hold question be improved?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27095/how-can-this-on-hold-question-be-improved)

So "pointless" is not a fair accusation when someone leaves a Comment of the kind you describe.  If you feel "frankly insulting" is the right interpretation, then so be it.  You are free to place whatever interpretation on Comments that you think is constructive.

Note that you are putting yourself in the position of those who ask Questions that elicit Comments, when you haven't actually asked any Questions yourself.  What you consider a constructive interpretation may change when you have to respond to a requested clarification.  It can be gratifying when the OP takes a Comment as a sign of constructive interest in their problem and responds in a way that does "progress the answer."  I made such a Comment today, which made the OP feel empowered to solve the problem themselves (and as a result, self-deleted their Question!).