# How can this on-hold question be improved?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question, asking-questions

This recently asked question by a new user:

[How to solve the inequality $2xy > x^2-y^2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2451671/9464)

is put on hold. OP wanted to solve an inequality and used [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) to get an answer. S/he did not understand how WolframAlpha would return the results and asked a question in the post.

[image]

This question is now on hold with the following instruction:

> "This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Here are my **questions**:

Is it possible to improve this question so that it will be reopened? What kind of additional contexts would you suggest to add to the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps my standards for requiring context are *de minimus*, but I think the OP of the (now deleted) Question meets the bar for asking.

The purpose of requiring context in my mind is (1) to ensure the poster has thought about what the problem means (avoiding esp. a "pass through" situation), and (2) to give Readers a notion of what the asker's level of understanding is.

It shouldn't be held to be a workable approach to the problem or even a correct understanding of it.  Many times the best of us must learn by working through a mistaken intuition or other fundamental error in understanding.

In this case the OP turned to Mathematica to get a solution to a quadratic inequality, and motivated by the typically awkward "solution statement" provided by that software, their curiosity was piqued: How can I get an answer like this?

I really think this is a wonderful setup for learning.  We should jump on such Questions with the hope of showing the user that they can get even more intelligible answers by simple algebraic methods.

I would favor undeleting and reopening such Questions.  I say as much without any special vested interest in the post, not having tried to answer it or voted on it in review.

**Added:** The [Question at issue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2451671/how-to-solve-the-inequality-2xy-x2-y2) has now been undeleted and reopened.